# Get segment of string in between characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a giant data set that includes lots of file names with various parts of strings that I need to grab.

I have this code segment currently:

```
def fps(data):
for i in data:
    pattern = r'.(\d{4}).' # finds data in between the periods
    frames = re.findall(pattern, ' '.join(data)) #puts info into frames list
    frames.sort()
for i in range(len(frames)): #Turns the str into integers
    frames[i] = int(frames[i])
return frames
```

This is great and all but it only returns 4 characters after and before a period. 
How would I grab part of the string after a period and before the next period. 
Preferably without using regular edit because it's a little too complex for a simpleton like me.

For example:
One string may look like this

```
string = ['filename.0530.extension']
```

while the others may look like this

```
string2 = ['filename.042.extension']
string3 = [filename.045363.extension']
```

I would need to output the numbers in between the periods on the terminal so:
 0530, 042, 045363

Comment: Give us some examples that should match and not match

Comment: Why are your strings in an array? It does not seem to be necessary. Also, I am surprised your badly indented code actually runs for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match your example data your could match a dot, capture in a group one or more digits `\d+` (instead of exactly 4 `\d{4}`) followed by matching a dot:

[`\.(\d+)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/cLbdgZ/1)

If you want to match all between the dots you might use a negating character class `[^.]` to match not a dot:

[`\.([^.]+)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/cLbdgZ/2)

**Note** that if you want to match a literal dot you should escape it `\.`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ZTKT17228)

Comment: So in the case of having several periods for example : 'filename_dot.test_s.0543.jpg' How would I get the numbers right before the extension?

Comment: In this case the pattern [`\.(\d+)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/PV4DXz/1) will capturine the digits. If the digits must be before the extension you might use [`\.(\d+)\.jpg$`](https://regex101.com/r/PV4DXz/2)

Comment: @Dr.Woo I've updated my answer to include different URLs. It will match both filename_dot.test_s.0543.jpg and filename.042.extension

Comment: Or you could use [`\.(\d+)\.[^.\r\n]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/PV4DXz/3) or an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match multiple extensions[`\.(\d+)\.(?:extension|jpg)$`](https://regex101.com/r/PV4DXz/4)

Comment: If you want a match instead of a capturing group, you might use a positive lookbehind [`(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.jpg$)`](https://regex101.com/r/PV4DXz/5) or multiple extensions [`(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.(?:jpg|extension)$)`](https://regex101.com/r/PV4DXz/6)

Answer (score 0):

To match the numbers between your periods in your example, you can use this:

`^.*\.[^.\s]*?\.?(\d+)\..*$`

[Here's an online example](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/20)

Comment: would i put that in place of r'.(\d{4}).' ?

Comment: Yes. You can refer to capture group 1 for the numbers in between